# CakePHP give response to Ajax post call from a different app

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, cakephp

I am trying to connect two apps, where one app creates an account for the second app. I'm currently doing it through an HTML form post request.

```
<body>

    <form action="https://example.com/users/add" method="post" id="my_form" target="_blank">
        Password: <input type="text" name="data[User][password]"><br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="data[User][email]"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <div id="result"></div>

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $("#my_form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var post_url = $(this).attr('action');
        var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        console.log("this");

        $.ajax({
            url: post_url,
            type: request_method,
            data: form_data,
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        })
    })
</script>
```

How can I send back a response to the post request from my second app.

```
    function add(){
        $response = array('status' => 'failed', 'message' => 'HTTP method not allowed');
        if($this->RequestHandler->isPost()){
            if(empty($data)){
                $data = $this->data;
            }
            $response = array('status'=>'failed', 'message'=>'Please provide form data');

            if(!empty($data)){
                if($this->User->save($data)){
                    $response = array('status'=>'success','message'=>'Product successfully created');
                }
                else{
                    $errors = $this->User->validationErrors;
                    $response = array('status'=>'failed', 'message'=>'Failed to save data', 'errors' => $errors);
                }
            }
        }
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
    }
```

Comment: Create an API Request.

Comment: Where your second app endpoint to call back?